# Storing different function pointers in one array?

Tags: c++, dictionary, function-pointers

If I have two functions like this:

```
void funcA(std::string str);

void funcB(int32_t i, int32_t j);
```

Can I store pointers to both of these functions in the same map? Example:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, SomeType> map;
map.emplace("funcA", &funcA);
map.emplace("funcB", &funcB);
map["funcA"]("test");
map["funcB"](3,4);
```

Would std::any work? or maybe some kind of template with std::function.

Edit:
Functions could also have different return types.
PS:
I am currently learning about Callbacks and Eventmanagers in videogames.

Comment: what should happen if you use the map to call funcA(3,4)?

Comment: I would try a functor with various overloads of `operator()`

Comment: It might be a match for `std::variant` and the visitor pattern, but in any case the question is why you’d want to combine functions like that and how they will be accessed and called. How about putting both of them into a polymorphic “interface” type and throwing some “unimplemented exception” from one of them (or having another `virtual` method to disambiguate which is which)?

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, I am currently learning how Event Managers work in game engines.  The book used the same arguemnts for every function, so I wanted to know if you could save functions with different signatures.

Comment: @aa So can we assume a pure curiosity question without real back ground? Otherwise you might suffer from a flawed design – and possibly be trapped in a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Aconcagua, you are correct, this question comes from bad design, I knew that, but I still wanted to know the answer if thats ok:)

Comment: @aa Asking just out of curiosity is always fine. And it's not about us to judge you for dropping (there are always good reasons for) or keeping (you might have some specific reasons for...) a bad design anyway. All we do is giving advice – and hints to where implications of the bad design might bite you sooner or later. Rest is up to you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for misunderstood, you can find a solution below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

typedef void (*customfunction)();

void hello() {
    std::cout<<"hello" << std::endl;
}

void hello_key(std::string value){
        std::cout<<"hello " << value << std::endl;
}

void hello_key_2(int value){
        std::cout<<"hello " << value << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    

    std::map<std::string, customfunction> function_map;
    
    function_map.emplace("test",customfunction(&hello));
    function_map.emplace("test-2",customfunction(&hello_key));
    function_map.emplace("test-3",customfunction(&hello_key_2));

    function_map["test"]();
    ((void(*)(std::string))function_map["test-2"])("yakup");
    ((void(*)(int))function_map["test-3"])(4);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I'd really prefer `reinterpret_cast`s here...

Answer (score -1):

Your functions have different types but `map` requires a single `value_type`. You can use `std::tuple` with types as "keys" and function pointers as "values":

```
void funcA(std::string) {}
void funcB(int32_t, int32_t) {}

int main() {
    std::tuple map{funcA, funcB};
    get<decltype(&funcA)>(map)("abc");
    get<decltype(&funcB)>(map)(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: How would you get funcA by string "funcA" (I'd assume these are just examples and actual keys are different...)? This means you don't answer the actual question, and thus (probably – not mine...) the downvote.

Comment: @Aconcagua OK. Well, if the key string is "`constexpr`" (like in the question), `decltype` works as well. If it isn't, I'll wait for more details. (@aa?)

Comment: Well, but if you need to have `&funcA` to get `funcA` itself, why wouldn't you use `funcA` directly? OK, you might try `get<void(*)(std::string)>`, but then you are bound to selection by static type, how would you select dynamically (like by a calculated string)?

Comment: @Aconcagua it gives you the stored function with `funcA`'s *signature*, so you don't need `funcA` itself - your `get` snippet is correct and usable. We don't know if dynamic type dispatch and/or dynamic function names are needed, waiting for @aa.